# Is there a way to determine which pragmas are active?

Tags: perl, pragma

I'm wondering if there's a way to determine what pragmas are active within a specific scope.

[`perlvar`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar) suggests `%^H` but it doesn't seem to do anything useful in the following one-liner:

```
$ perl -e 'use strict; use warnings; use utf8; use Data::Printer; p %^H'
{}
```

I ask since it took me quite a while to figure out that an implicit `utf8` pragma loaded by `Mojolicious::Lite` was creating trouble that my `Regexp::Grammars` tests had failed to capture, and I hope there's a better way to troubleshoot such problems.

Answer (score 2):

`%^H` is for making your own pragmas. `strict`, `warnings` and `utf8` all set bits in [`$^H`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$%5EH).

But changes to both `$^H` and `%^H` are restored at the end of the BEGIN block being executed. So you need to use [`caller`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller) to access their value at run-time.

```
$ perl -e'
   use Data::Printer;

   sub f {
      CORE::say sprintf "%X", (caller(0))[8];
      p %{ (caller(0))[10] // {} };
   }

   {
      use strict;
      use warnings;
      use utf8;
      f();
   }

   {
      f();
   }
'
8007E2
{}
0
{}
```